# Html entities form JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

In my ifone App, i have called a php page to get contents, it returns JSON format,but the response contains Html entities like `&quot;`.How i convert these entities to unicode.Any methods or libraries in objective C.

help is highly appreciated,
Shihab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem you can use SBJSON class and will get result in the dictionary json by following code

```
NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJSON *jsonParser = [SBJSON new];
NSMutableDictionary *json = [jsonParser objectWithString:stringResponse error:NULL];
```

Comment: thanks for ur immediate response, i have used the same but html entities is there

Comment: NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  
 NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
 results= [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];